# Permanently set default zoom in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I set the zoom level to 110% in Visual Studio on my home PC and it's always saved that way. I have never once needed to change it after it was set the first time I opened the program. That was the case in both 2015 and 2017. I just got a new work PC, however, and it does not remember my zoom level at all. I have to reset it every time I open any new file.

I'm using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ResetZoom), which allows me to set the default to 110% and go to that with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, but this isn't ideal as I have to do it upon opening ANY file.

How can I *permanently* set the default zoom level in VS 2015?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the Viasfora extension; it was resetting the zoom each time. I disabled this in Tools > Options > Viasfora > Presentation Mode > uncheck "Enable Presentation Mode".

Comment: @mikerodent i mean, it does, given it was their question,